# How do I search a string "backwards"?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following code in Angular. I want to be able to find "north america" by typing "america north". How do I do that?

```
const getContinents = keys =>
  [
    'africa',
    'antarctica',
    'asia',
    'australia',
    'europe',
    'north america',
    'south america'
  ].filter(e => e.indexOf(keys.toLowerCase()) > -1);

const fakeContinentsRequest = keys =>
  of(getContinents(keys)).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log(`API CALL at ${new Date()}`))
  );

fromEvent(document.getElementById('type-ahead'), 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    map((e: any) => e.target.value),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(fakeContinentsRequest),
    tap(c => (document.getElementById('output').innerText = c.join('\n')))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: How about `str.split(" ").reverse().join(" ").includes(searchText)`?

Comment: IMO your best course is to split your search term by spaces and search the results for each term, rather than trying to manage every possible permutation.

Answer (score 3):

You could [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) both string on spaces to get an array of each word.

Then we can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if `input` exist in `search`. This way the 'order' is not important.

Combining this with [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the matching result in an array:

```js
const options = [ 'africa', 'antarctica', 'asia', 'australia', 'europe', 'north america', 'south america' ];
        
function findByWord(input) {
  let inputSplit = input.split(' ');
  return options.filter(o => o.split(' ').every(e => inputSplit.includes(e)));
}


const res = findByWord('america north');
console.log(res)
```

```json
[
   "north america"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is just to reverse those words you've been given, and assume all casing is correct:

```js
const matchStr = "I Love PHP";
const searchStr = "PHP Love";
if (matchStr.includes(searchStr.split(" ").reverse().join(" "))) {
    console.log("Value matched: " + matchStr);
}
```

To implement into your current code, a little more annoying but you can just add an OR condition to your `filter` line:

```
.filter(e => (e.indexOf(keys.toLowerCase()) > -1) || (e.indexOf(keys.toLowerCase().split(" ").reverse().join(" ")) > -1));
```

Comment: no, because i dont necessarily want to type "PHP Love". Its a search, not an algorithm.

Comment: check out my updated question

Comment: @user14850280 Check the updated answer - and that was an example, just put the logic where you need it and substitute variable names. The second code snippet should work for you.

Comment: @user14850280 search is an algorithm…

Answer (score 1):

I made something more dynamic, where I split the search string and then loop through them inside an `Array.filter()`. It's possible that it's easier to achieve this using a regexp. I also added a requirement that the search should ignore words that are shorter than two characters, and also mapped the keywords to be lowercase so they are case insensitive.

```js
const continents = [
  'africa',
  'antarctica',
  'asia',
  'australia',
  'europe',
  'north america',
  'south america'
]

const filterContinents = (searchStr, continents) => {
  const MIN_KEYWORD_LENGTH = 2;
  let keywordsArr = searchStr.split(' ')
    .filter((keyword) => keyword.length > MIN_KEYWORD_LENGTH)
    .map((keyword) => keyword.toLowerCase());
  let hasKeywords = keywordsArr.length > 0;

  const filterByKeywords = (_contintent) => {
    for (const _keyword of keywordsArr) {
      if (!_contintent.includes(_keyword)) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return hasKeywords
  }

  return continents.filter(filterByKeywords);
}


let searchStr = 'eur';
console.log({searchStr}, filterContinents(searchStr, continents));

searchStr = 'eu ro pe';
console.log({searchStr}, filterContinents(searchStr, continents));

searchStr = 'America North';
console.log({searchStr}, filterContinents(searchStr, continents));
```